# What is P(B-complement|A-complement) in that case?

Tags: probability

Suppose that a drawer contains 8 marbles: 2 are red, 2 are blue, 2 are green, and 2 are yellow. The marbles are rolling around in a drawer, so that all possibilities are equally likely when they are drawn. Alice chooses 2 marbles without replacement, and then Bob chooses 2 marbles. Let A denote the event that Alice's 2 marbles have a matching color. Let B denote the event that Bob's 2 marbles have a matching color.

Find P(A|B-complement).

I kniw that I'll be using Baye's rule to get the answer but there's one probability that I can't calculate, P(B-complement|A-complement).

Answer (score 0):

> I kniw that I'll be using Baye's rule to get the answer

You won't. (Or at least, you needn't.)

$\mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement)$ is the probability that Alice has drawn a pair when given that Bob has drawn two unpaired marbles.

The conditioned space is of drawing two marbles from two pairs and two singletons of some colours; with all outcomes equally probable.   How many outcomes is that?   The favoured event is of drawing one of the pairs; how many outcomes is that?   Divide and calculate.

Comment: I'm kind of a rookie in probability. Could you illustrate with numbers?

Comment: $\uparrow$ There are numbers right there.  What is the probability for selecting *one* from the *two* pairs when selecting *two* items from all *six*?